# Dynamic Column name changes every year in where clause

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to automate a TSQL select statement on a website. Each year the column names change with the number values at the end of the name increasing by 1 so instead of manually updating the site I'm trying to figure out how to include the dynamic column name in the where clause.

The data looks something like this.

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
| FY18 | FY19 | FY20 | FY21 | FY22 |
+------+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    1 |
|    1 |    1 |    0 |    1 |    0 |
|    1 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    0 |
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Here is what I've come up with so far... The select statement looks something like this

```
  Select distinct
    POS
    from TBL_Staff
    where [' 'FY'+right(year(dateadd(month,3,getdate()))-1,2) '] = 1
```

What I'm trying to figure it out is if there is a way to dynamically generate the date and get SQl to recognize name+date as a column

Note: This is fake data so please let me know if something isn't clear

Any help on this is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Select distinct
    POS
    from TBL_Staff
    where FY' + CAST(right(year(dateadd(month,3,getdate()))-1,2) AS VARCHAR) + '  = 1'

    exec sp_executesql @sql
```

@sql is a variable that is used to construct a SQL statement dynamically. Then the sp_executesql procedure executes it. Beware of using dynamic sql when other alternatives exist. It's harder to read, can be difficult to maintain, and can be a security issue if taking input from users and you're not careful to sanitize input parameters.

Comment: That worked beautifully! I had to add tons of quotes ' to make sure the other parts of the query were included in the string the dynamic bit was being added to. Had a lot more going on in the where clause in the original code!

Comment: Glad it helped! Yes, escaping the single quotes can get tricky in really complicated queries lol